# multy query grouping with condition

Tags: android, mysql

I have this table resulting from query, but i would like obtain another query

**QUERY**

```
SELECT cp_store, nome, qty FROM tb_store WHERE  data_out is null
```

**RESULT**

```
cp_store  name    qty
"Cp1"   "pesto" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "jivara"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Nocciola"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Parfait"   "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Crema" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Crema" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Malaga"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Ricotta_Limone"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "mango" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Lampone"   "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Limone_zenzero"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Caramello_Salato"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "albicocca" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Pistacchio"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato"    "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Bacio_Siculo"  "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
"nice1" "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
```

from this table is possible to obtain a query with this result?
(add single qty group by name, but separately by **cp_store** name

```
cp_store  name    qty
 "Cp1"  "Cioccolato"    "6.0"
 "Cp1"  "Cioccolato_al_rum" "1.0"
"Cp1"   "Bacio_Siculo"  "3.0"
 "nice1"    "Cioccolato_al_rum" "2.0"
 "nice1"    "Bacio_Siculo"  "3.0"
.
.
.
.
.
```

and so on

Comment: Is the column's name `qta` or `qty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cp_store, nome, SUM(CAST(qta AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS total FROM tb_store WHERE  data_out is null GROUP BY cp_store, nome ORDER BY cp_store, nome
```

Comment: @user8959091 is possible to compare the result with another table, where inside of this there are the name of flavors? like this:
id  name                          presence    cp_store
1."Cioccolato"   "1" "All"
2."Bacio_Siculo"  "1" "All"
3."Ricotta_Limone"         "1" "All"
4."Cioccolato_al_rum" "1" "All"
5."Pistacchio"          "1" "All"
6."Nocciola"          "1" "nice1"
7."Mascarpone"  "1" "Cp1"
the result of compare is the sum of ingredient that are present and the other the sum are 0. I hope to be clear. thanks